# How to get all Object3D's from a Canvas in three-react-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm working on my first App using react-three-fiber. I currently generate the Viewport like this:

```
const Viewport = (props) => {

  return (
    <Canvas
      onCreated={({ gl, raycaster }) => {
        gl.setClearColor("darkgrey");
        props.setraycaster(raycaster);
      }}
    >
      {/* Canvas Config */}
      <CameraControls />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />

      {/* Objects */}
      {props.scene.objects.map((o, i) => (
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingBox />} key={i}>
          <Element3D obj={o} displaymode={props.displaymode} key={i} />
        </Suspense>
      ))}
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I'm taking a model of what should be displayed in the Viewport in the props, and then displaying them as Element3D components in a canvas.
I also want to do raycasting in another part of my App, to check occlusion between objects. For this, I need to tell the raycaster all objects it should consider.
So, I need a list of all Object3Ds that end up on my Canvas. My question is how I would get such a list.

In case you need to know, this is the important part of the Element3D component:

```
const scene = useLoader(OBJLoader, props.obj.meshPath);

return (
  <primitive object={scene.children[0]}>
    {
      <meshBasicMaterial
        attach="material"
        transparent
        side={THREE.DoubleSide}
      >
        <primitive attach="map" object={texture} />
      </meshBasicMaterial>
    }
  </primitive>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Gonna answer my own question here to say that *Canvas* has the attribute *scene*, which is of Type *Scene*, which inherits from *Object3D*. So, I just modified the *onCreated* of my viewport to pass the scene up

```
const Viewport = (props) => {

  return (
    <Canvas
      onCreated={({ gl, raycaster, scene }) => {
        gl.setClearColor("darkgrey");
        props.setRaycaster(raycaster);
        props.setScene3(scene)
      }}
    >
      {/* Canvas Config */}
      <CameraControls />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />

      {/* Objects */}
      {props.scene.objects.map((o, i) => (
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingBox />} key={i}>
          <Element3D obj={o} displaymode={props.displaymode} key={i} />
        </Suspense>
      ))}
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

I can just pass that scene to my raytracer, and voila, it considers all objects in the Viewport.

Comment: You can also put refs on all your object3d 
```let myobject3drefs=useRef()
<somenewobject3d ref={(element)=>myobject3drefs.push(element)} />
and then use them like so 
for(let cur of myobject3drefs.map(ob=>{return ob.current}))
console.log(cur.name)```